# Dynamically update a Mapbox GL expression to show or hide geometries

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to dynamically show or hide single geometries on a map, based on whether they're selected by a user. I understand that this isn't directly supported by Mapbox GL js, so I'm trying to figure out what the best workaround is. I'd prefer not to update the source data and then call `map.getSource('mysource').setData(data);` as this seems like overkill.

Is it possible to instead dynamically update an expression and call `setPaintProperty`, such that one subset of data is set to 0 % opacity, thus hiding it? I could then recompute the subset and re-set the property when required:

- user clicks `hide` button, which passes a `Feature`'s uniquely-identifying property to my function
- the function gets the existing `hidden` and `shown` subsets, then moves the `Feature`'s identifier from one to another by dynamically re-writing the two expressions.
- The new expression is passed to `map.setPaintProperty('layer', 'opacity', expression);`

The total number of geometries is quite small (< 100), and they aren't particularly complex, so I don't think this will be too inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some property on each feature like an ID, and an array of the ones that should be shown, the usual way to do this is simply:

```
map.setFilter(layer, '==', ['get', 'id'], arrayOfIds);
```

It's also possible to do it like you suggested, making some of them transparent, something like:

```
map.setPaintProperty(layer, 'line-opacity', ['match', ['get', 'id'], 
    arrayOfIds, 1.0,
    0]
);
```

And various other combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I had to make few changes, to get setFilter function from accepted answer to work.
"match" instead of "=="
true, false as last two parameters
second parameter to setFilter function is array ['match', ...]

It looks like this:

```
map.setFilter('layer', ['match', ['get', 'id'], arrayOfIds, true, false])
```

I'm using mapbox-gl 2.10.0